# Taking a Screenshot of an iPhone app mixing UIKit and OpenGL

Tags: iphone, graphics, uikit, opengl-es, screenshot

So, I know how to take a screenshot with UIKit:

```
UIWindow *window = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(window.bounds.size);
[window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

And I know how to take a screenshot with OpenGL

```
// Some preparation to read pixels into a buffer
glReadPixels(0,0,backingWidth, backingHeight, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);
// Some code to massage the raw pixel data into an image
```

My app mixes OpenGL and UIKit, so any screenshot taken with just one method doesn't look right.

What's the best way to either
a) Composit the two images together or
b) Take a screenshot that can capture both OpenGL and UIKit together

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/35789-programatically-getting-screenshot-opengl-content.html) is a similar post which has some answers. Apparently you can use either `UIGetScreenImage`, or `glReadPixels` to do this task. Hope that helps!